# Fluent NHibernate Unit Testing fixed length character fields

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate

I have a unit test that is failing and I know why but I'm not sure how I should be handling it. I have the following unit test:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<OrderLine>(session)
       .CheckProperty(x => x.Line, "1")
       .VerifyTheMappings();
```

It is failing with the following error:

Test method CanCorrectlyMapOrderLine threw exception: 
System.ApplicationException: For property 'Line' expected '1' of type 'System.String' but got '1         ' of type 'System.String'

The reason it's doing this is because x.Line points to a fixed length character field in the database (nchar(10) to be exact) and when it inserts the data it pads it with spaces.  Should I be specifying "1" with 9 spaces at the end in my unit tests or should I be trimming this somehow when I read it in?  Is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing the following with this:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<OrderLine>(session)
   .CheckProperty(x => x.Line, "1".PadRight(10, ' '))
   .VerifyTheMappings();
```